# Hbase-Spark Connector issue in cloudera: java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write Spark dataframe into Hbase, but when I perform any action or write/save method on the same dataframe it gives the following exception:

```
{
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
        at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseFilter$.log(HBaseFilter.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseFilter$.buildFilters(HBaseFilter.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseTableScanRDD.getPartitions(HBaseTableScan.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
----------

    Here is my code:




    import org.apache.spark.sql.{SQLContext, _}
    import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase._
    import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

    def catalog = s"""{
         |      |"table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"Contacts"},
         |      |"rowkey":"key",
         |      |"columns":{
         |      |"rowkey":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key", "type":"string"},
         |      |"officeAddress":{"cf":"Office", "col":"Address", "type":"string"},
         |      |"officePhone":{"cf":"Office", "col":"Phone", "type":"string"},
         |      |"personalName":{"cf":"Personal", "col":"Name", "type":"string"},
         |      |"personalPhone":{"cf":"Personal", "col":"Phone", "type":"string"}
         |      |}
         |  |}""".stripMargin

    def withCatalog(cat: String): DataFrame = {
         |          spark.sqlContext
         |          .read
         |          .options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog->cat))
         |          .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase")
         |          .load()
         |      }

    val df = withCatalog(catalog)

    i was able to create dataframe, but i perform 
    df.show()
```

it gives me error:

```
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError
     at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.log(Logging.scala:50)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseFilter$.log(HBaseFilter.scala:121)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseFilter$.buildFilters(HBaseFilter.scala:124)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.HBaseTableScanRDD.getPartitions(HBaseTableScan.scala:60)`
```

please give some suggestions:
  i am impoting table form Hbase and creating catlog and based on that creating dataframe on top of that using:-
  Spark 1.6
  HBase 1.2.0-cdh5.13.3 
  cloudera

Answer (score 0):

Same problem encountered, I'm using hbase-spark 1.2.0-cdh5.8.4.

I've tried compiling it on version 1.2.0-cdh5.13.0, after that the error no longer exists. You should try to recompile the source code or use higher version.